# Legal data segement constructions

Tags: assembly, x86-16, data-segment

I would like to get some help with this questions:
what is correct and legal in following definition of the data segment:

```
data segment 
     x db -23, 3 or 4, not -3, 9 xor 15, 129, $+x, SEG x, -128 LT 80h 
     db -129, x+1, b2h, 256, 7852h, byte ptr z 
     y dw z-2, -7852h, x[2], offset bx 
     z dd z-y, FAR PTR y 
data ends
```

I consider following wrong:

```
- cant contain operations:  3 or 4, not -3, 9 xor 15,  FAR PTR y, offset bx ...
- cant reference same varaible : $+x
```

And correct:

```
- -23, 129, 7852h ...
- a db 'abc'
  lengthOfa EQU ($-s)
```

Am i right about this facts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you let the assembler answer? `x`, `y`, `z` are only labels, **not** variables. So you can separate the values and write them in several lines. Consider to keep the declarations (`db`, `dw`, `dd`). Build an assembly source text, let it assemble and look which line contains which error:

```
data segment
     x db -23
     db 3 or 4
     db not -3
     db 9 xor 15
     db 129
     db $+x         ; TASM: Can't add relative quantities - MASM: error A2101: cannot add two relocatable labels
     db SEG x       ; TASM: Not expecting group or segment quantity - MASM: error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size
     db -128 LT 80h

     db -129
     db x+1         ; TASM: Expecting scalar type - MASM: error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size
     db b2h         ; TASM: Undefined symbol: B2H - MASM: error A2006: undefined symbol : b2h
     db 256         ; TASM: Value out of range - MASM: error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size
     db 7852h       ; TASM: Value out of range - MASM: error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size
     db byte ptr z  ; TASM: Expecting scalar type - MASM: error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size
     y dw z-2
     dw -7852h
     dw x[2]
     dw offset bx   ; TASM: Illegal use of register - MASM: error A2032: invalid use of register
     z dd z-y
     dd FAR PTR y
data ends

code segment
start:
    ret
code ends

end start
```

Comment: good point   forgot i can acutally add flags to my linker and compiler... :))